# Compile and run different jdk within one jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

I would like to receive jenkins job that first compiles tests with java 8 and then run them with java 11. Gradle is used in the project, which has lots of subprojects. Is it even possible?
I tried with approach (which was actually the best I came up with)

```
tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {
    options.with {
        fork = true
        forkOptions.javaHome = [java-8-home]
    }
}
```

placed in main `build.gradle` but I am not sure if this will affect all compile type tasks in subprojects/tasks in other directories.
Then I invoked gradle task with `-Dorg.gradle.java.home=[java-11-home]`

Let me know what do you think, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is perfectly possible. Let's check step by step how this *can* be done. First of all, we instruct Gradle to compile all Java sources with Java 8 source and target compatibility and execute compilation with a Java 8 executable taken from environment variable `JAVA8_HOME`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.with {
        fork = true
        forkOptions.javaHome = System.env.'JAVA8_HOME' as File
    }
}
```

Running the build with the `--info` switch shows that the Java 8 executable is indeed taken from the environment variable `JAVA8_HOME` and applies to all Java compilation tasks.

```
> Task :compileJava
Compiling with Java command line compiler 'C:\dev\java\jdk-8\bin\javac.exe'.

> Task :compileTestJava
Compiling with Java command line compiler 'C:\dev\java\jdk-8\bin\javac.exe'.
```

Executing tests with Java 11 taken from environment variable `JAVA11_HOME` works in a similar manner.

```
test {
   executable = "${System.env.'JAVA11_HOME'}/bin/java"
}
```

This produces again the following output:

```
> Task :test
Command: C:\dev\java\jdk-11/bin/java -Dorg.gradle.native=false ...
```

### Subprojects

Applying this configuration to all subprojects in a multi-module project is straight forward. The following shows a root project's `build.gradle` that applies all rules only to those sub-projects having the Java plugin applied.

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

allprojects {
    plugins.withId('java') {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        java {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.with {
                fork = true
                forkOptions.javaHome = System.env.'JAVA8_HOME' as File
            }
        }

        test {
            useJUnitPlatform()

            executable = "${System.env.'JAVA11_HOME'}/bin/java"
        }

        dependencies {
            testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
            testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")
        }
    }
}
```

Since you now depend on having environment variables set up, it makes sense to check them before actually starting the build. This can be done by checking the task graph once ready:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.getAllTasks().find { it instanceof JavaCompile } != null
            && (System.env.'JAVA8_HOME' == null || System.env.'JAVA11_HOME' == null)) {
        throw new GradleException("Please export 'JAVA8_HOME' and 'JAVA11_HOME'")
    }
}
```

### Jenkins

In Jenkins, all you need to do is to make sure to install the required JDKs and export the environment variables properly. A [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) *may* look like this (take it with a grain of salt, I didn't test it yet):

```
pipeline {
    tools {
        jdk 'jdk-8'
        jdk 'jdk-11'
    }

    environment {
        JAVA8_HOME = "${tool 'jdk-8'}"
        JAVA11_HOME = "${tool 'jdk-11'}"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                checkout scm

                sh "./gradlew --no-daemon --info --stacktrace clean build"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow...that looks pretty awesome. Will try to implement it with my case. Thanks!